# Copy paste HTML&PHP code and replace in order $variable[value]

Tags: php, html

I need to copy/paste a code 400 times and i need to have the value from the PHP variable in numerical order as
Simplified code is as below

```
<div>
  <a><img width="270" height="161" alt="" src="<?php echo $img[0][0];?>"></a>
  <p><?php echo $variable[0];?></p>
</div>
<div>
  <a><img width="270" height="161" alt="" src="<?php echo $img[1][0];?>"></a>
  <p><?php echo $variable[1];?></p>
</div>
...........
<div>
  <a><img width="270" height="161" alt="" src="<?php echo $img[400][0];?>"></a>
  <p><?php echo $variable[400];?></p>
</div>
```

Any ideea of a software name or Dreamweaver/Notepad++ funtion on how can i do this.?

Comment: Em.... you gave the answer yourself: `php`. All you need to do is implement a simple "for" loop.

Comment: What? Why?  `for` loop and increment a counter.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php foreach ( $img as $key => $val ): ?>
<div>
  <a><img width="270" height="161" alt="" src="<?php echo $val[0];?>"></a>
  <p><?php echo $variable[$key];?></p>
</div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

[Here](http://www.tehplayground.com/#T38hGlQ2b) is a working example.

Comment: Or just `echo $val[0]`